# Upgrading A visual studio 2010 MVC application to VS 2012 MVC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, visual-studio-2012

I have upgraded to VS 2012 from VS2010 and I had my application automatically converted but I am facing a strange intellisence issue on my views. none of the intellisence work on things like @model or when I try and do @Html.EditorFor(.....) I thought that was because of some missing library or so after checking the web.config of my views all reference are there. strange thing is If I create a new MVC project inside the VS 2012 application, then I gain access to all these, as I have a lot of views I was wondering if there is a way or a setting the need altering on the project side or something else.

just a small clarification, I am still on MVC4 Razor same as what it was in VS2010

Answer (score 0):

I believe this affects any sorts of projects, not just MVC.

In my case I used the info there:
http://www.haneycodes.net/visual-studio-2012-intellisense-not-working-solved/?goback=.gde_43315_member_188049241

and cleaned my machine fully... I had to wipe out anything related to VS2010 including from the AppData folder.
After a full clean up, Intellisense works again in VS2012 but if by any chance I open VS 2010 on the same project, then intellisense is immediately broken in VS 2012.